# Ubuntu won't recognise and use my nvidia geforce gtx 1050 ti GPU

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver, devices

Hello wizards of linux,

I'm a complete linux noob, though I've got experience with nearly every windows after 98. I just built a new pc and while I wait for my windows installation disk to ship I decided to install ubuntu and check it out.

After installation, I opened one of my favorite linux compatible games, xonotic (www.xonotic.org), only to find my FPS count was horrid. I quickly realized that linux wasn't using my GPU. First, I checked my BIOS to make sure it was set to actually use it by default, which it was. Then, I went back into ubuntu. I figured ubuntu needed a driver installed, so I went to the driver manager only to find out that the only device on the list was errored and unidentified. Wonderful, eh? So, I realized that I couldn't install the driver from there, so before I did anything else I ran some command I found that would show me my gpu stats, and as expected the only thing ubuntu knew was that it was an nvidia card. Helpful!

Well, I had no way of knowing whether or not the GPU was broken, and due to my monitor being plugged into it's dvi port I thought it was fine.

So, I downloaded the driver and fiddled around for an hour before I figured out how to install it. I installed it, and I got the same issue.

I noticed a lot of other people are having similar problems, does anybody here know the solution? Until I get windows in some days, I won't know if something is actually wrong with my GPU.

Also, thanks for listening to a complete noob.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers on how to install the proprietary drivers you need for making use of your GPU.